# C# Thread not releasing memory

Tags: c#, multithreading, memory-management

I have a windows service written in C#.Net. When the service is started, I spawn a new thread as shown below

```
new Thread(new ThreadStart(Function1)).Start();
```

This thread loops infinitely and performs the duties expected of my service. Once a day, I need to simultaneously perform a different operation for which my thread spawns a second thread as show below

```
new Thread(new ThreadStart(Function2)).Start();
```

This second thread performs a very simple function. It reads all the lines of a text file using FileReadAllLines , quickly processes this information and exits.

My problem is that the memory used by the second thread which reads the file is not getting collected. I let my service run for 3 hours hoping that the GC would be called but nothing happened and task manager still shows that my service is using 150mb of memory. The function to read and process the text file is a very simple one and I am sure there are no hidden references to the string array containing the text. Could someone shed some light on why this is happening? Could it be possible that a thread spawned by another spawned thread cannot cleanup after itself?

Thanks

Comment: I think it would help to actually see the code that's being run on the 2nd thread.

Comment: Does your second thread correctly dispose the stream used to read the file?

Comment: And did you forget to dispose any ressource when reading the file?

Comment: How do you know that you've got a leak. Just reading numbers out of task manager is notoriously error prone. Unless you actually know how Windows memory management works, and .net memory management, then you'll misinterpret the numbers.

Comment: It's difficult to understand problem, but i can suggest you to use ThreadPool instead of creating new threads manually or use System.Threading.Timer - it's usual practice in WinServices to schedule some background work.

Comment: GC won't be called if there isn't any pressure on the memory.

Comment: "Using 150 megs of memory" is quite literally *meaningless*. Is that "memory" that you're using address space? If it is, how much of it is shared?  Of the unshared working set, how much of it is allocated, how much is committed, and how much is in physical memory instead of page file?  Until you know the answers to all those questions, analysing memory usage is pointless. But frankly, 150 megs is *tiny* and you probably shouldn't be worrying about it. Can you explain why you care? Also, don't use task manager. Use a memory profiler to analyze memory usage, that's what it's for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Windows task manager to try to work out the memory used, it's likely to be deceiving you. Memory used by the CLR isn't generally returned to the operating system as far as I'm aware... so you'll potentially still see a high working set, even though most of that memory is then still available to be reused within the process.

If you let the service run for a week, do you see the memory usage climb steadily through the week, or does it just increase in the first day, and then plateau? If so, do you definitely view this as a problem? If so, you may need to put your second task in a separate process.

Comment: This is probably the solution. Is there any way to force memory to be returned to the operating system or is this something that will automatically happen if another application needs this memory?

Comment: @newidforu: You have plenty of virtual memory in the operating system... although I believe the GC may respond to global pressure. I confess to not being terribly clear on *exactly* what happens in terms of memory. You ideally don't want "wasted" memory to be swapped, but that may end up happening...

Answer (score 11):

Trust the garbage collector and stop worrying. 150 megs is nothing. You aren't even measuring the size of the file in that; most of that will be code.

If you are concerned about where memory is going, start by understanding how memory works in a modern operating system. You need to understand the difference between virtual and physical memory, the difference between committed and allocated memory, and all of that, before you start throwing around numbers like "150 megs of allocated memory". Remember, you have 2000 megs of virtual address space in a 32 bit process; I would not think that a 150 meg process is large by any means.

Like Jon says, what you want to be concerned about is a slow steady rise in private bytes. If that's not happening, then you don't have a memory leak. Let the garbage collector do its job and don't worry about it.

If you *are* still worried about it good heavens do not use task manager. Get a memory profiler and learn how to use it. Task manager is for inspecting processes by looking down on them from 30000 feet. You need to be using a microscope, not a telescope, to analyze how the process is freeing the bytes of a single file.

Comment: Thanks. The microscope, not a telescope made me smile

Comment: Probably the best tool to start with is Process Explorer (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653). It has a bunch of .NET specific info

Comment: Process Explorer is pretty useful, but I'd be more apt to start with the CLR Profiler (Download [1.1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=86ce6052-d7f4-4aeb-9b7a-94635beebdda&displaylang=en) , [2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13382) , [4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=16273) )